# Run Next line after application.Run()

Tags: c#, console-application, keylogger

My requirement is to get keyspressed when user opens specific URL in chrome.
For that I am firstly checking for URL opened in chrome after that I am setting hook using below code

```
    _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    Application.Run();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
```

it is getting the keys on that URL but after that if i close that URL it is continuously getting the keys, that's what i don't want.
It is because I am calling application.run(). How to run the code after application.run()? I think that would be the solution

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The call to `Aplication.Run` is blocking as it starts the Windows Message loop. That call will return once the main window gets closed and/or one of the messages (for example [WM_QUIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-quit)) that will end a windows program is being received and handled by the message loop

If you want to run code after the Run method has been called, one option would be to register a handler on the [Application.Idle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle(v=vs.110).aspx) event

```
_hookID = SetHook(_proc);
Application.Idle += (s,e) => { UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);};
Application.Run();
```

In my testing the Idle event is raised, once the `Run` method is called an no other messages are handled by the main message loop.

Alternatively gracefully exit your windows loop, for example by posting WM_QUIT to its top window.

Comment: Hey Rene, what it doing is when i open secipic URL it is binding the keylogger event only for one time, so it is not working when i pressed second key on that URL but i want to capture whole word

Comment: i have changed it for whole word, it is capturing whole word , all good, can you pleae refer what to use for the next time i open the URL it will capture the same.